# Why am I receiving this error in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I cannot figure out why I'm getting the following error when running a query. Done just about every search possible for this as it pertains to my issue. Code is good as far as I can tell. Any ideas?

ORA-06550: line 17, column 42:
PLS-00201: identifier 'IDPLEDGE' must be declared

My code:

```
 DECLARE 
   f_payflag    VARCHAR2(25); --flag for test condition
   CURSOR cur_pledges IS
     SELECT idpledge, pledgeamt, paymonths, paydate, payamt, iddonor  
       FROM DD_PLEDGE JOIN DD_PAYMENT
            USING (IDPLEDGE)
      WHERE idpledge = 302
      ORDER BY idpledge, paydate;
 BEGIN
   FOR rec_iddonor IN cur_pledges LOOP
     IF cur_pledges%ROWCOUNT = 1 
     THEN 
       f_payflag :='First Payment';
     ELSE 
       f_payflag := NULL;
     END IF;
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Pledge ID: ' || idpledge || 
                        ' Pledge Amount: $' || pledgeamt || 
                        'Monthly Payment: $'|| paymonths ||
                        'Pay Date: ' ||  paydate || 
                        ' Amount Paid: $' || payamt ||
                        ' ' || f_payflag);    

 END;
```

Comment: There is no column named `idpledge` into tables `DD_PLEDGE` and `DD_PAYMENT`

Comment: @LucM: That's crazy talk. The problem is the reference to `idpledge` in the call to `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. That's the identifier that PL/SQL can't resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's useful to format your code.  If you consistently indent, you'll find that a lot of mistakes jump out at you.

In this case, the first mistake is that your `dbms_output.put_line` call is happening after the end of your loop.  That doesn't make sense.  Assuming that you are trying to write a row of output for every row returned in your cursor, you'd want the `dbms_output` call to be inside the loop.

The second mistake is that all the variables you are trying to reference in your `dbms_output` call do not exist.  There is no local variable `idpledge` or `pledgeamt` for example.  My guess is that you intended to refer to values from the `rec_iddonor` pseudorecord.  Since that pseudorecord only exists within the loop, that tends to support my guess that you wanted to print the values from inside the loop.  You'd then need to use the pseudorecord explicitly when referencing the fields.

My guess is that you want something like

```
 DECLARE 
   f_payflag    VARCHAR2(25); --flag for test condition
   CURSOR cur_pledges IS
     SELECT idpledge, pledgeamt, paymonths, paydate, payamt, iddonor  
       FROM DD_PLEDGE JOIN DD_PAYMENT
            USING (IDPLEDGE)
      WHERE idpledge = 302
      ORDER BY idpledge, paydate;
 BEGIN
   FOR rec_iddonor IN cur_pledges LOOP
     IF cur_pledges%ROWCOUNT = 1 
     THEN 
       f_payflag :='First Payment';
     ELSE 
       f_payflag := NULL;
     END IF;

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Pledge ID: ' || rec_iddonor.idpledge || 
                          ' Pledge Amount: $' || rec_iddonor.pledgeamt || 
                          ' Monthly Payment: $'|| rec_iddonor.paymonths ||
                          ' Pay Date: ' ||  rec_iddonor.paydate || 
                          ' Amount Paid: $' || rec_iddonor.payamt ||
                          ' ' || f_payflag);    

   END LOOP;

 END;
```

Comment: that was the trick. Pasted an incorrect version of the code with the DBMS output incorrectly outside the loop. Appreciate the advice on syntax indentation. Learning little by little.